# Pivot a table in KQL

Tags: pivot, pivot-table, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a table that looks like the one below. String values inside the table can be completely different and don't necessarily follow some set naming rules. Integer values may be more than just 0, 1, 2.

```
let input = datatable (name:string, test_name:string, value:int)
[
    "VM01", "test_1", 0,
    "VM01", "test_2", 1,
    "VM01", "test_3", 1,
    "VM01", "test_4", 2,
    "VM01", "test_5", 2,
    "VM02", "test_1", 2,
    "VM02", "test_2", 1,
    "VM02", "test_3", 1,
    "VM02", "test_4", 1,
    "VM02", "test_5", 2,
    "VM03", "test_1", 1,
    "VM03", "test_2", 1,
    "VM03", "test_3", 1,
    "VM03", "test_4", 0,
    "VM03", "test_5", 2,
    "VM04", "test_1", 1,
    "VM04", "test_2", 1,
    "VM04", "test_3", 1,
    "VM04", "test_4", 1,
    "VM04", "test_5", 2,
    "VM05", "test_1", 1,
    "VM05", "test_2", 1,
    "VM05", "test_3", 2,
    "VM05", "test_4", 2,
    "VM05", "test_5", 1,
];
```

I want to write a query that transforms it into this:

| test_name | VM01 | VM02 | VM03 | VM04 | VM05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test1 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| test2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| test3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| test4 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| test5 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: Not sure what was the challenge here for you if you are already familiar with the term *pivot*.

Comment: I didn't know about take_any()

Comment: Got it. *min* / *max* would have given the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/pivotplugin) plugin

```
let input = datatable (name:string, test_name:string, value:int)
[
    "VM01", "test_1", 0,
    "VM01", "test_2", 1,
    "VM01", "test_3", 1,
    "VM01", "test_4", 2,
    "VM01", "test_5", 2,
    "VM02", "test_1", 2,
    "VM02", "test_2", 1,
    "VM02", "test_3", 1,
    "VM02", "test_4", 1,
    "VM02", "test_5", 2,
    "VM03", "test_1", 1,
    "VM03", "test_2", 1,
    "VM03", "test_3", 1,
    "VM03", "test_4", 0,
    "VM03", "test_5", 2,
    "VM04", "test_1", 1,
    "VM04", "test_2", 1,
    "VM04", "test_3", 1,
    "VM04", "test_4", 1,
    "VM04", "test_5", 2,
    "VM05", "test_1", 1,
    "VM05", "test_2", 1,
    "VM05", "test_3", 2,
    "VM05", "test_4", 2,
    "VM05", "test_5", 1,
];
input
| evaluate pivot(name, take_any(value))
```

| test_name | VM01 | VM02 | VM03 | VM04 | VM05 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test_1 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| test_2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| test_3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| test_4 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| test_5 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA3XSvQrDIBQF4F3wHS6ZEsiQ%20LOk9BG6diklWCpFmtrQ3AQKffgaN8Wry8Uj8iFnsgjOzyvCEe4Gw75NFmpvXnZY8OP8owW0C47JyWam1Q7OY8PZhTMIqzqfur5qoYq396lrS4kIU19MJJmoMIliorNEJIJykgsEKRCJoJzkApkI%20mKSCyQpkImgKya5QJECRQoUKVDkHyhSoEmBJgU6EZRfy3ugE8H%202vXAWawzZz%20we00NWpjd9sbY6VBm87Sj8d86drhp/lZklDQBAwAA)